# Index creation in Data Generator

Tags: mysql, sql, datagrip

I'm generating a script from an existing MySQL schema using DataGrip's SQL Generator feature. I obtain a working script containing `create index` statements. I would prefer the indexes to be created by a `key` clause in the `create table` statement. I can't see an option in SQL Generator to get that. Do I miss something? I have dozens of tables, so I can't just do it by hand.

The server is a MySQL 5.7.

Comment: I would strongly consider upgrading to MySQL 8.x or MariaDB 10.5. MySQL 5.7 is reaching end of life next year.

Comment: I'm fully aware of that. It is unrelated to my problem, though.

Comment: Not a solution, but my [very personal] take is that I typically keep indexes separated from table creation. In my thinking (I can be totally off) indexes are not part of the SQL Standard, and second they tend to be created, updated, deleted a lot *after* the table creation; this typically happends when you need to optimize queries later on.

Comment: The script I'm currently maintaining has for sole purpose to be able to rebuild a database from scratch.

Comment: @TheImpaler I don't think the question is related to the version of MySQL I'm using, so I removed the "mysql 5.7" tag.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using not the SQL Generator, which doesn't seem to be able to do what I want, but a raw export of the database structure. I select the schema (you can select various and multiple objects: schemas, tables, triggers, produres, functions), on right-click: SQL Scripts -> Request and Copy original DDL, which copies the resulting script extracted from the database. You can then paste it wherever you want, for example a SQL console or a text editor.

Answer (score 0):

You can use *SQL Generator | Generate: Definitions provided by RDBMS server* to get the same result
[image]